# Ruby on Rails - generate devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am new to Ruby on Rails. Just installed it and upgraded rubygems as well. When I type `ruby new project` I get the following at the end:

```
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
Warning: You're using Rubygems 2.0.14 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0 and run `gem pristine --all` for better startup performance.
* bin/rake: spring inserted
* bin/rails: spring inserted
```

I checked ruby version and it was:

```
ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin14]
```

Rails version:

```
Rails 4.2.0
```

I tried to install `devise` by adding the following command `gem 'devise'` to `Gemfile`, then ran `gem install devise` to get the following:

```
Fetching: thor-0.19.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed thor-0.19.1
Fetching: thread_safe-0.3.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed thread_safe-0.3.5
Fetching: tzinfo-1.2.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed tzinfo-1.2.2
Fetching: i18n-0.7.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed i18n-0.7.0
Fetching: activesupport-4.2.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activesupport-4.2.1
Fetching: rails-deprecated_sanitizer-1.0.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rails-deprecated_sanitizer-1.0.3
Fetching: mini_portile-0.6.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mini_portile-0.6.2
Fetching: nokogiri-1.6.6.2.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.6.6.2
Fetching: rails-dom-testing-1.0.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rails-dom-testing-1.0.6
Fetching: loofah-2.0.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed loofah-2.0.1
Fetching: rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.2
Fetching: erubis-2.7.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed erubis-2.7.0
Fetching: builder-3.2.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed builder-3.2.2
Fetching: actionview-4.2.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed actionview-4.2.1
Fetching: rack-1.6.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rack-1.6.0
Fetching: rack-test-0.6.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rack-test-0.6.3
Fetching: actionpack-4.2.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed actionpack-4.2.1
Fetching: railties-4.2.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed railties-4.2.1
Fetching: responders-2.1.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed responders-2.1.0
Fetching: bcrypt-3.1.10.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed bcrypt-3.1.10
Fetching: orm_adapter-0.5.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed orm_adapter-0.5.0
Fetching: warden-1.2.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed warden-1.2.3
Fetching: devise-3.4.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed devise-3.4.1
Parsing documentation for thor-0.19.1
Installing ri documentation for thor-0.19.1
Parsing documentation for thread_safe-0.3.5
Installing ri documentation for thread_safe-0.3.5
Parsing documentation for tzinfo-1.2.2
Installing ri documentation for tzinfo-1.2.2
Parsing documentation for i18n-0.7.0
Installing ri documentation for i18n-0.7.0
Parsing documentation for activesupport-4.2.1
Installing ri documentation for activesupport-4.2.1
Parsing documentation for rails-deprecated_sanitizer-1.0.3
Installing ri documentation for rails-deprecated_sanitizer-1.0.3
Parsing documentation for mini_portile-0.6.2
Installing ri documentation for mini_portile-0.6.2
Parsing documentation for nokogiri-1.6.6.2
Installing ri documentation for nokogiri-1.6.6.2
Parsing documentation for rails-dom-testing-1.0.6
Installing ri documentation for rails-dom-testing-1.0.6
Parsing documentation for loofah-2.0.1
Installing ri documentation for loofah-2.0.1
Parsing documentation for rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.2
Installing ri documentation for rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.2
Parsing documentation for erubis-2.7.0
Installing ri documentation for erubis-2.7.0
Parsing documentation for builder-3.2.2
Installing ri documentation for builder-3.2.2
Parsing documentation for actionview-4.2.1
Installing ri documentation for actionview-4.2.1
Parsing documentation for rack-1.6.0
Installing ri documentation for rack-1.6.0
Parsing documentation for rack-test-0.6.3
Installing ri documentation for rack-test-0.6.3
Parsing documentation for actionpack-4.2.1
Installing ri documentation for actionpack-4.2.1
Parsing documentation for railties-4.2.1
Installing ri documentation for railties-4.2.1
Parsing documentation for responders-2.1.0
Installing ri documentation for responders-2.1.0
Parsing documentation for bcrypt-3.1.10
Installing ri documentation for bcrypt-3.1.10
Parsing documentation for orm_adapter-0.5.0
Installing ri documentation for orm_adapter-0.5.0
Parsing documentation for warden-1.2.3
Installing ri documentation for warden-1.2.3
Parsing documentation for devise-3.4.1
Installing ri documentation for devise-3.4.1
Done installing documentation for thor, thread_safe, tzinfo, i18n, activesupport, rails-deprecated_sanitizer, mini_portile, nokogiri, rails-dom-testing, loofah, rails-html-sanitizer, erubis, builder, actionview, rack, rack-test, actionpack, railties, responders, bcrypt, orm_adapter, warden, devise after 21 seconds
23 gems installed
```

I tried then to run the following command: `rails g devise user` but I still keep getting the following: `Warning: You're using Rubygems 2.0.14 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0 and run`gem pristine --all`for better startup performance.` and nothing happens.

How can I proceed?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to the warning about rubygems, you can run:

```
gem update --system
```

Then make sure you do the following in order:

1. Add devise to your Gemfile
2. Run `bundle` in the command line
3. Run `rails g devise:install` in the command line
4. Run `rails generate devise User` in the command line.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Rubygems update:

```
gem install rubygems-update
update_rubygems
```

should help to get rid of that rubygems 2.0.14 warning.